# taking parameter as a string and converting to number in javascript

Tags: javascript

What my issue is that my client will enter the values in any other language. suppose marathi. i need to create bill according to input.
what i have done is i took the input taken by user as string and assigned value to them this is working till 0-9 but what about 10, 100, 1000 and so on..
here is my code,plz suggest

```
function convert_number()
            {
                 var no1 = document.getElementById('rate').value
                if(no1 == "०")
                {
                    no1 = 0;
                    alert(no1);
                }
                else if(no1 == "१")
                {
                no1 = 1;
                alert(no1);             
                }
                else if(no1 == "२")
                {
                no1 = 2;
                    alert(no1);
                }
                else if(no1 == "३")
                {
                no1 = 3;
                    alert(no1);
                }
                else if(no1 == "४")
                {
                no1 = 4;
alert(no1);             
                }
                else if(no1 == "५")
                {
                no1 = 5;
alert(no1);             
                }
                else if(no1 == "६")
                {
                no1 = 6;
alert(no1);             
                }
                else if(no1 == "७")
                {
                no1 = 7;    
                alert(no1);
                }
                else if(no1 == "८")
                {
                no1 = 8;
alert(no1);             
                }
                else if(no1 == "९")
                {
                no1 = 9;
alert(no1);             
                }
                else
                {
                alert('invalid')    
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will help in JavaScript.

Create a 2D array like this `var nos=[['०',0],['१',1],['२',2]];` and add local digit in first index and original numbers in second index like I did.

**Sample code included below**
Try typing a marathi digit in the textbox and the click on the button. then check console

```js
var nos=[['०',0],['१',1],['२',2],['३',3],['४',4],['५',5],['६',6],['७',7],['८',8],['९',9]];
function convert_number(num){
  if(typeof num!=typeof 123){
    var i=0;
    if(num.length>1)
      return convertmore(num);
    while(i<nos.length){
      if(nos[i][0]==num){
        return nos[i][1];
      }
      i++;
    }
 }
 else{
  return num;
 }
}
function convertmore(num){
  var i=num.split('');
  var result=0;
  i.forEach(function(x){
    result*=10;
    result+=convert_number(x);
  });
  return result;
}
```

```html
<input id="num" type="text" />
<button onclick="console.log(convert_number(document.getElementById('num').value));">Convert</button>
```

Comment: sorry, but it's working only for single digit, i need to do it for 2 digit, 3 digit and 4 digit values

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, it is a key. You have to extend the array

Comment: @manzuboy edited. now you can try any number. for example, try ४५

Answer (score 1):

You could [get the UTF-16 code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) of the character, so you wouldn't need even a switch

```js
var no1 = document.getElementById('rate').innerHTML

alert(no1.charCodeAt(0));
```

```html
<p id="rate">r</p>
```

Comment: so should i pass the number at  str.charCodeAt(index)  index parameter??

Comment: You give the position of the character, of a given string, for which you want the character code. For instance, by doing `alert(no1.charCodeAt(0));`, you get the UTF-16 numeric code of no1 at the first position. I've added a running example

Comment: it will return the ASCII value. but OP want to convert from one language to another. like Roman V-> 5

Comment: @SagarV So you say that he needs to map characters of multiple languages? By converting to UTF-16 value you get an integer, then you could map integers (characters) between them.

Comment: Just give a try on this `"०".charCodeAt(0)` in console. The required output is 0.

Comment: @SagarV OP has accepted your answer, so clearly it fits the needs.

Answer (score 1):

This code would convert numbers above and below 0-9:

```
var map = {"-":"-","०":0,"१":1,"२":2,"३":3,"४":4,"५":5,"६":6,"७":7,"८":8,"९":9};
function convert(str) {
  var converted_str = '';
  if (str.split('').find(char => {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(char))
      converted_str += map[char];
    else
      return true;
    }) === true) {
    return NaN;
  } else {
    return parseInt(converted_str);
  }
}
```